# Running Periodic tasks on elastic beanstalk workers with FIFO queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sqs

I was trying to setup a periodic task (using **cron.yaml**) in **EB worker environment** which is using a **FIFO SQS queue**. When cron job tries submit job to SQS, it fails because it does not have message group id which is required for FIFO queue.

Is there a way around this? (Apart from using some other scheduling mechanism or using general queue)

> scheduler: dropping leader, due to failed to send message for job
>   'italian-job', because: The request must contain the parameter
>   MessageGroupId. (Aws::SQS::Errors::MissingParameter)

> **Update:**    As a work around, I created a cloud watch trigger to start a lambda which sends messages to SQS queue.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this, I am hitting the same thing?

Comment: @AnthonyWebb Nope, I ended up setting a cloud watch trigger + lambda which submits the task to SQS queue.

Comment: Also hitting the same thing. Any luck? https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/wisdom_of_the_ancients.png

Answer (score 0):

From Amazon's docs:

> Note: If you configure your worker environment with an existing SQS queue and choose an Amazon SQS FIFO queue, periodic tasks aren't supported.

Only [standard](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/standard-queues.html) queues are supported for periodic tasks, not [FIFO](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-queues.html) queues.

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html#worker-periodictasks